# Java - How can I make a variable, that is assigned a value in on object, accessible to all objects?

Tags: java

I am trying to assign the variable gross a value in the default constructor and then have the other methods be able to access it (the calc... methods).

```
public class CO2FromWaste
{
CO2FromWaste(int numPeople, boolean paper, boolean plastic, boolean glass, boolean cans)
{
    public double ogGrosss = numPeople*1018;
    public double grosss = ogGrosss;

    if(paper = true)
        gross -= 184*numPeople;
    if(plastic = true)
        gross -= 25.6*numPeople;    
    if(glass = true)
        gross -= 46.6*numPeople;
    if(cans = true)
        gross -= 165.8*numPeople;    
}
private double gross = ogGrosss;
private double ogGross = Grosss;
public void calcGrossWasteEmission()
{
    System.out.printf("%20.2f", gross);
}
public void calcWasteReduction() 
{
    System.out.printf("%20.2f", ogGross - gross);
}   
public void calcNetWasteReduction()
{
   System.out.printf("%20.2f", gross);
}    
}
```

Comment: Just make those variables class level variables.

Comment: The variables _are_ declared as class level variables (also) in the middle of the code (just after the constructor) but are not ever assigned values. Just remove the declarations **in** the constructor, which will make the assignments affect the class variables instead of the local variables.

Comment: There seems to be a major misunderstanding w.r.t. the concept of objects, variables and attributes. Please consider (re-)reading a tutorial on these topic, e.g. the [official Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Comment: `if (paper = true)` causes paper to be assigned to true then true is given to the if statement. it is the same as `paper = true; if (paper)`. Change the `=` to `==`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is for those variables to be members of the class — as you have it now they are declared locally to the constructor.

```
public class CO2FromWaste
{
    // Moved your variables to here, outside of any method.
    // They should be declared at/near the top of the class,
    // *before* the constructor (by convention)
    // I also made them `private` because you don't want code
    // that is *outside* of this class to access them.
    private double ogGrosss;
    private double grosss;

    CO2FromWaste(int numPeople, boolean paper, boolean plastic, boolean glass, boolean cans)
    {
        // Now assign them their values.
        // You can optionally use `this`
        this.ogGrosss = numPeople*1018;

        if(paper == true)
            gross -= 184*numPeople;
        if(plastic == true)
            gross -= 25.6*numPeople;    
        if(glass == true)
            gross -= 46.6*numPeople;
        if(cans == true)
            gross -= 165.8*numPeople;    
    }

    // removed the declarations from here - these were now duplicates.

    public void calcGrossWasteEmission()
    {
        System.out.printf("%20.2f", gross);
    }
    public void calcWasteReduction() 
    {
        System.out.printf("%20.2f", ogGross - gross);
    }   
    public void calcNetWasteReduction()
    {
        System.out.printf("%20.2f", gross);
    }    
}
```

Note the `=` operator in `if(paper = true)` is *assignment* — you want to *compare* these variables, which is done with the `==` operator.

(untested. I didn't even try to compile this, just modified your code)

Also note that when you subtract a floating-point value from the variable `gross`, it will round down the result.

Comment: I appreciate it. This makes more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add some tips you can use to improve upon Stephen P's answer.

First of all, there is never any reason to compare against a boolean.  Instead of `paper == true` you can simply write `paper`.  All an if statement needs is a boolean value.  If the value is already boolean, you do not need to perform a comparison.  Therefore, your if statements can be made more readable by changing them to:

```
if(paper)
    gross -= 184*numPeople;
if(plastic)
    gross -= 25.6*numPeople;
if(glass)
    gross -= 46.6*numPeople;
if(cans)
    gross -= 165.8*numPeople;
```

I am assuming that based on what your code does that only one of the four boolean variables you use in your constructor should be true at a time, any the rest should be false.  If this *is* the case, I would recommend using an enum to denote the options, otherwise you leave your class vulnerable to logic errors when used incorrectly.  You would add the following file to your project:

WasteMaterial.java

```
public enum WasteMaterial {
    PAPER, PLASTIC, GLASS, CANS
}
```

And modify the constructor for your class like so:

```
CO2FromWaste (int numPeople, WasteMaterial material)
{
    // Now assign them their values.
    // You can optionally use `this`
    this.ogGrosss = numPeople*1018;

    switch (material) {
    case PAPER:
        gross -= 184*numPeople;
        break;
    case PLASTIC:
        gross -= 25.6*numPeople;
        break;
    case GLASS:
        gross -= 46.6*numPeople;
        break;
    case CANS:
        gross -= 165.8*numPeople;
        break;
    }
}
```

This prevents the class from being constructed incorrectly by setting multiple values to `true` (*if*, of course, your specification only allows one of those four values to be `true` at a time).